# How to send message to webapp based on an event on mobile app

Tags: java, spring, events, websocket

How to send the message to web application when an event occurs on the mobile app. both are using same backend server.I was using WebSocket and I was able to trigger the message.Is this is the right way to do it ? here is my code.

webscoket handler

```
public class MyHandler extends TextWebSocketHandler {
    @Autowired
    private CommonUtil util;

    @Override
    public void handleTextMessage(WebSocketSession session, TextMessage message) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        while(true){
            Iterator<String> it1 = util.membership_attendance_list.keySet().iterator();
            while (it1.hasNext()) {
                String key = it1.next();
                String membershipId = util.membership_attendance_list.get(key);
                session.sendMessage(new TextMessage(membershipId));
                util.membership_attendance_list.remove(membershipId);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

App will be communicating to this api

```
public class AttendanceController{

@Autowired
    private CommonUtil util;

        @RequestMapping(value = "/attendance", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = "Accept=application/json")
    public Response saveAttendance(@Valid @RequestBody final AttendanceDto dto)){
        final Response response = new Response();
        // implimentation logic goes here
        util.membership_attendance_list.put(eventParticipantMap.getMemberShipId(),eventParticipantMap.getMemberShipId());
        return response;
    }

}
```

is it possible to impliment it using listener ?

Comment: Yes. It is the right way. But you have to keep in mind some facts about websocket:
1) It doesn't guarantee the messages order or even if the client will get the message
2) If the webclient wasn't connected to websocket and server tries to send the message, webclient won't get it later. If you need something like guaranteed delivery, you have to implement or use smth like STOMP.

Comment: Also you have to put the connecting to the websocket to js (or what you are using) part. Because you can't refresh users web page from server.

Answer (score 0):

So if we are talking about Mobile App based events. I am going to give an android based example, but similar concepts can be found out for other platforms. There are certain event listeners with call-back methods for each type of events. Typically you need to override the abstract callback methods of the listener interface or abstract class and register your method behavior there for making an HTTP POST/GET/SOCKET_SEND of every occurrence of the event.

I am familiar with Android-based apps. So here's an example for the same:

**The Event Listener and Callback Method**

public class EventExampleActivity extends Activity {

```
@Override
protected void onStart()
{
        super.onStart();

        Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.myButton);

        //for listening simple click events
        button.setOnClickListener(
                //registering callback method behaviour here. 
                new Button.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                     // the data related to the events can be fetched
                     // in the v object
                     // insert http get/post/socket_send logic here
                }
            }
        );

        //for listening long click events
        button.setOnLongClickListener(
            new Button.OnLongClickListener() {
                //registering callback method behaviour here.
                public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                 // the data related to the events can be fetched
                 // in the v object
                 // insert http get/post/socket_send logic here
                return true;
            }
        }
    );

    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

For more on event listeners.
https://guides.codepath.com/android/Basic-Event-Listeners
https://www.tutlane.com/tutorial/android/android-input-events-event-listeners-event-handling